# Recode a variable using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, recode

I am trying to recode a variable using data.table. I have googled for almost 2 hours but couldn't find an answer.

Assume I have a data.table as the following:

```
DT <- data.table(V1=c(0L,1L,2L),
                 V2=LETTERS[1:3],
                 V4=1:12)
```

I want to recode V1 and V2. For V1, I want to recode 1s to 0 and 2s to 1. 
For V2, I want to recode A to T, B to K, C to D.

If I use `dplyr`, it is simple.

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
  mutate(V1 = recode(V1, `1` = 0L, `2` = 1L)) %>% 
  mutate(V2 = recode(V2, A = "T", B = "K", C = "D"))
```

But I have no idea how to do this in data.table

```
DT[V1==1, V1 := 0]
DT[V1==2, V1 := 1]
DT[V2=="A", V2 := "T"]
DT[V2=="B", V2 := "K"]
DT[V2=="C", V2 := "D"]
```

Above is the code that I can think as my best. But there must be a better and a more efficient way to do this.

---

**Edit**

I changed how I want to recode V2 to make my example more general.

Comment: I think your `V2` will likely have to be character since you want to change `"C"` to `"D"` correct? Although I may be mistaken about exactly how you want to recode `V2`

Comment: @MikeH. Yes, `V2` will likely have to be character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for. On the left hand side of `:=` we name the variables we want to update and on the right hand side we have the expressions we want to update the corresponding variables with.

```
DT[, c("V1","V2") := .(as.numeric(V1==2), sapply(V2, function(x) {if(x=="A") "T" 
                                                     else if (x=="B") "K" 
                                                     else if (x=="C") "D" }))]

 #   V1 V2 V4
 #1:  0  T  1
 #2:  0  K  2
 #3:  1  D  3
 #4:  0  T  4
 #5:  0  K  5
 #6:  1  D  6
 #7:  0  T  7
 #8:  0  K  8
 #9:  1  D  9
#10:  0  T 10
#11:  0  K 11
#12:  1  D 12
```

Alternatively, just use `recode` within `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
DT[, c("V1","V2") := .(as.numeric(V1==2), recode(V2, "A" = "T", "B" = "K", "C" = "D"))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find a data.table equivalent of `dplyr`'s `recode`. So I changed my example to a more general case.

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific function like `recode` in `data.table`. However you can use `recode` within `data.table` like: `DT[, c("V1","V2") := .(as.numeric(V1==2), recode(V2, "A" = "T", "B" = "K", "C" = "D"))]`

Comment: Or, you could use other functions like `sapply`: `DT[, c("V1","V2") := .(as.numeric(V1==2), sapply(V2, function(x) {if(x=="A") "T"
                                                                  else if (x=="B") "K"
                                                                  else if (x=="C") "D"
                                                                  }))]`

Comment: Just a word of caution: Using `as.numeric(V1==2)` to forge `2L` into `1L` and any other number into `0L` is a really clever R trick. But its a trick which only works in this special situation. E.g., It will break if  `V1` would contain any other numbers.

Answer (score 20):

With `data.table` the recode can be solved with an *update on join*:

```
DT[.(V1 = 1:2, to = 0:1), on = "V1", V1 := i.to]
DT[.(V2 = LETTERS[1:3], to = c("T", "K", "D")), on = "V2", V2 := i.to]
```

which converts `DT` to

```
    V1 V2 V4
 1:  0  T  1
 2:  0  K  2
 3:  1  D  3
 4:  0  T  4
 5:  0  K  5
 6:  1  D  6
 7:  0  T  7
 8:  0  K  8
 9:  1  D  9
10:  0  T 10
11:  0  K 11
12:  1  D 12
```

**Edit**: @Frank suggested to use `i.to` to be on the safe side.

#### Explanation

The expressions `.(V1 = 1:2, to = 0:1)` and `.(V2 = LETTERS[1:3], to = c("T", "K", "D"))`, resp., create lookup tables *on-the-fly*.

Alternatively, the lookup tables can be set-up beforehand

```
lut1 <- data.table(V1 = 1:2, to = 0:1)
lut2 <- data.table(V2 = LETTERS[1:3], to = c("T", "K", "D"))

lut1
```

> ```
>    V1 to
> 1:  1  0
> 2:  2  1
> ```

```
lut2
```

> ```
>    V2 to
> 1:  A  T
> 2:  B  K
> 3:  C  D
> ```

Then, the *update joins* become

```
DT[lut1, on = "V1", V1 := i.to]
DT[lut2, on = "V2", V2 := i.to]
```

#### Edit 2: Answers to *How can I use this code dynamically?*

[mat asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590935/recode-a-variable-using-data-table/44592473?noredirect=1#comment125605674_44592473) "*How can I use this code dynamically?*"

So, here is a modified version where the name of column to update is provided as a character variable `my_var_name` but the lookup tables still are created *on-the-fly*:

```
my_var_name <- "V1"
DT[.(from = 1:2, to = 0:1), on = paste0(my_var_name, "==from"), 
   (my_var_name) := i.to]
my_var_name <- "V2"
DT[.(from = LETTERS[1:3], to = c("T", "K", "D")), on = paste0(my_var_name, "==from"), 
   (my_var_name) := i.to]
```

There are 3 points to note:

1. Instead of naming the first column of the lookup table dynamically it gets a fixed name `from`. This requires a join between differently named columns (*foreign key join*). The names of the columns to join on have to be specified via the `on` parameter.
2. The `on` parameter accepts character strings for *foreign key joins* of the form `"V1==from"`. This string is created dynamically using `paste0()`.
3. In the expression `(my_var_name) := i.to`, the parentheses around the variable `my_var_name` forces to use the contents of `my_var_name`.

#### Dynamic code using pre-defined lookup tables

Now, while the column to recode is specified dynamically by a variable, the lookup tables to use are still *hard-coded* in the statement which means we have stopped halfways: We need also to select the appropriate lookup table dynamically.

This can be achieved by storing the lookup tables in a list where each list element is named according to the column of `DT` it is supposed to recode:

```
 lut_list  <- list(
  V1 = data.table(from = 1:2, to = 0:1),
  V2 = data.table(from = LETTERS[1:3], to = c("T", "K", "D"))
)
lut_list
```

> ```
> $V1
>     from    to
>    <int> <int>
> 1:     1     0
> 2:     2     1
>
> $V2
>      from     to
>    <char> <char>
> 1:      A      T
> 2:      B      K
> 3:      C      D
> ```

Now, we can pick the appropriate lookup table from the list dynamically as well:

```
my_var_name <- "V1"
DT[lut_list[[my_var_name]], on = paste0(my_var_name, "==from"), 
   (my_var_name) := i.to]
```

Going one step further, we can recode *all* relevant columns of `DT` in a *loop*:

```
for (v in intersect(names(lut_list), colnames(DT))) {
  DT[lut_list[[v]], on = paste0(v, "==from"), (v) := i.to]
}
```

Note that `DT` is *updated by reference*, i.e., only the affected elements are replaced *in place* without copying the whole object. So, the `for` loop is applied iteratively on the same data object. This is a speciality of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and will not work with data.frames or tibbles.

Comment: How can I use this code dynamically? For instance with `my_var_name <- "V1"`. I tried `DT[.(get(my_var_name) = 1:2, to = 0:1), on = my_var_name", get(my_var_name) := i.to]` without success.

Comment: @mat, please, see my edit.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Wonderful answer!!! It's a pitty do not find this well documented throught data.table vignettes/man pages.

Answer (score 2):

mapvalues() from plyr, in combination with data.table, works really well.

I use it on large-ish data (50 mio - 400 mio rows). Although I haven't benchmarked it as compared to other possibilities, I find the clear syntax is worth a lot, as it means fewer errors in complicated recode operations.

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)


DT <- data.table(V1=c(0L,1L,2L),
                 V2=LETTERS[1:3],
                 V4=1:12)


DT[, V1 := mapvalues(V1, from=c(1, 2), to=c(0, 1))]
DT[, V2 := mapvalues(V2, from=c('A', 'B', 'C'), to=c('T', 'K', 'D'))]
```

For more complicated recode operations, I would always create a new variable first with NA, and use another data.table with from-to vectors as variables.

A feature that in some use-cases is more of a bug is that mapvalues() keeps those values from the old variable that isn't in the from argument. 
This is a problem if you're sure that all the correct values is in the from-vector, so that any values in the data.table that isn't in this vector should be NA instead.

```
DT <- data.table(V1=c(LETTERS[1:3], 'i dont want this value transfered'),
                 V4=1:12)
map_DT <- data.table(from=c('A', 'B', 'C'), to=c('T', 'K', 'D'))


# NA variable to begin with is good practice because it is clearer to spot an error  
DT[, V1_new := NA_character_]
DT[V1 %in% map_DT$from , V1_new := mapvalues(V1, from=map_DT$from, to=map_DT$to)][]
```

note that plyr is deprecated, so the mapvalues-function is somewhat at risk of disappearing at some point in the future. the update-joins method proposed might be a better method because of this, although I find mapvalues to be just a tad clearer to read. although it will probably take years before mapvalues is deprecated, most likely, a lot of years. But still, something to keep in mind when deciding to use it as a tool or not.