# Sum by specific group and rename

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame (I took an exemple from antoher post but it works for question)

```
library(data.table)
```

```
data = data.table(Category=c("First","First","First","Second","Third", "Third", "Second"), 
                  Frequency=c(10,15,5,2,14,20,3))
```

And I'd like to sum by First and group all the other under the name of "Others" like this

```
data2 <- data.table(category = c("First", "Others"), Frequency = c(30,39))
```

How can I do this ?
thank you

**EDIT**

I have edit my df and it looks like

```
data = data.table(Category=c("First","First","First","Second","Third", "Third", "Second"), 
                  Frequency=c(10,15,5,2,14,20,3),
                  Bloc=c("B1","B2","B1","B1","B1","B2","B1") 
)
```

How can I do in order to get

```
data2 <- data.table(category = c("First","First","Others" "Others"), Frequency = c(15,15,19,20), Bloc = c(B1,B2,B1,B2)
```

Thanks

Comment: see this post for diffferent options of recoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590935/recode-a-variable-using-data-table

Comment: I corrected it thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `replace` all the categories which are not `'First'` to `'Other'` and the `sum` by group.

```
library(data.table)
data[, Category := replace(Category, Category != 'First', 'Other')]
data[, .(Frequency = sum(Frequency)), .(Category, Bloc)]

#   Category Bloc Frequency
#1:    First   B1        15
#2:    First   B2        15
#3:    Other   B1        19
#4:    Other   B2        20
```

Comment: When I try, I get this error message ; " Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")."

Comment: Are you using it on the data that you shared? Your data needs to be `data.table`. According to the error message it doesn't look like that it's a `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without changing the original dataset

```
 library(data.table)
 group <- "First"


 ingroup <- sum(data$Frequency[data$Category == group])
 not_ingroup <- sum(data$Frequency[! data$Category == group])

 data.table(Category = c(group, "Others"), Frequency=c(ingroup, not_ingroup) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(Category=c("First","First","First","Second","Third", "Third", "Second"), 
                  Frequency=c(10,15,5,2,14,20,3))


data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Category = case_when(
    Category == 'First' ~ "First", 
    TRUE ~ 'Other'
  )) %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Frequency = sum(Frequency)) %>% 
  group_by(Category, Frequency) %>% 
  summarise(Category = first(Category))
```

[image]